# how to use enumerate with regex(findall) in python?

Tags: python, regex, enumerate

I have a txt file as follows,

```
#onetwothree.txt
>one 
QWERTYUIOP
>two
ASDFGHJKL
>three
ZXCVBNM
...
```

and I want to split that txt file into several files as follows,

```
#one.txt
>one
QWERTYUIOP
```

and

```
#two.txt
>two
ASDFGHJKL
```

and

```
#three.txt
>three
ZXCVBNM
```

here is the code I worte,

```
import re
with open("onetwothree.txt") as file:
 name=re.findall(r'\>[^\n]+',file.read())
 sequence=re.findall(r'name[ind][^/n]+' for ind in enumerate(name), file.read())
          .
          .
          .
```

I know that there is something wrong in following part.

`sequence=re.findall(r'name[ind][^/n]+' for ind in enumerate(name), file.read())`

I want to make a list using `re.findall`,`enumerate` 
and following list is what I want to get.

```
>>>print (seq)
["QWERTYUIOP","ASDFGHJKL","ZXCVBNM"]
```

how can I fix this code`sequence=re.findall(r'name[ind][^/n]+' for ind in enumerate(name), file.read())` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't read a file twice using `read()`, second time you call it, it returns an empty string.

Also, i think you got the wrong understanding of `re.findall`. It takes only 2 parameters (regex,string).

You can accomplish the task in one go, without calling `findall` twice.

```
s = '''>one 
QWERTYUIOP
>two
ASDFGHJKL
>three
ZXCVBNM
''' # replace this with file.read()

res = re.findall(">([^\n]+)\n(\w+)",s)     #each regex in paren constitutes a group
print(res) 
#[('one ', 'QWERTYUIOP'), ('two', 'ASDFGHJKL'), ('three', 'ZXCVBNM')]
```

Comment: thanks for your advice! I'm just studying Python by myself so there are lot of things I didn't understand! anyway, thanks for your answer!